# A question about sum of probability... if $P(X\ge n)-P(X=n)=P(X>n)$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, power-series

If we know that $P(X\ge n)=(1-p)^{n-2}$
*(This is not the main subject of the question, so I wont explain about it, hope this OK, but in sort: we get it because $P(X\ge n)=\sum_{k=n}^\infty (1-p)^{k-2}\cdot p$ )*.

So,

1. It true that: $P(X\ge n)-P(X=n)=P(X>n)$?
2. $P(X>n)=(1-p)^{n-1}$ if we use what was given at the beginning (because instead of $k=n$ we put $k=n+1$) ?

I add one more Q:
So: $P(X=n)=(1-p)^{n-2}-(1-p)^{n-1}$???

If I'm wrong please fix my mistake, anyway, I have to find a way to calculate $P(X>n)$...

Thank you!

P.S. - **The question is about *discrete* probability...**

Comment: Yes, both things are true. The somewhat unusual thing is that we have an almost geometric distribution, except that the random variable only takes on values $\ge 2$. So although the assertios are correct, I wonder whether there might have been a slip in the work that led to the question.

Comment: Yes, at the question $R_X=\left\{2,3,4,.....\right\}$, Thank you @AndréNicolas !

Comment: @AndréNicolas, so at this question (that I posted here) - $P(X=n)=(1-p)^{n-2}-(1-p)^{n-1}$??

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you want to "simplify" you can take out a common factor of $(1-p)^{n-2}$. Then you get $(1-p)^{n-2}(1-(1-p))$, which is $p(1-p)^{n-2}$.

Comment: @Yoar You should add $n$ stands for an integer and that rv $X$ takes values on $\mathbb Z$. Discrete means only that $P\{X\in C\}=1$ for some countable set $C$. It is not necessary that $C=\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 1):

If your distibution is discrete, that is not continuous, we have that
$$
P(X = n) = P(X\ge n) - P(X\ge n+1) =P(X\ge n) - P(X>n),
$$
so indeed the first equation is true. Actually it is also true for continuous distributions, but also useless as $P(X=x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: A probability is by definition discrete if there is a countable set $C$ with $P(C)=1$. However, this set $C$ is not necessarily a subset of $\mathbb Z$. So just 'being discrete' is not enough as condition.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I'll leave the answer anyway as I think it is applicable in the specific situation of Yoar

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing discrete probability, then those statements are valid. Otherwise, they are technically correct, but do not really mean anything as continuous probability makes no distinction between "less than" and "less than or equal to."

Comment: That's not completely true. "If heads then $X = 0$, if tails then $X$ is a Gaussian" gives an example where $P(X > 0)$ is different from $P(X \geq 0)$.

Comment: @nik But that's not completely continuous :)

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint events, i.e. $A\cap B=\emptyset$, then $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$. Applying that on $A=\{X>n\}$ and $B=\{X=n\}$ gives: $$P\{X\ge n\}=P\{X>n\}+P\{X= n\}$$

By the same reasoning $P\{X> n\}$  will equalize $P\{X\ge n+1\}$ if and only if $P\{X\in (n,n+1)\}=0$. So if that condition is satisfied then:$$P\{X\ge n\}=P\{X\ge n+1\}+P\{X= n\}$$